# Some questions about observable in Angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have wrote a service in Angular which is used to manage the localstorage state.

It names localStorage.service.ts and the `providers: [LocalStorageService]` is in app.module.ts

the code is just like

```
observer: Observer<any>;
observable: Observable<any>;

setKey(key, item){
    localStorage.setItem(key, item);
    observer.next("change");
}
constructor(){
    this.observable = new Observable(obs => {
      this.observer = obs;
      window.addEventListener("storage", event => { obs.next("change") });
    });
}
```

however, when I subscribe it in other components
eg: a.component.ts

```
import { Storage } from "localStorage.service";
```

an then

```
constructor(private storage:Storage){
    storage.subscribe(change => {
        console.log("1");
        console.log("2");
    })
    storage.set('test', 'test');
}
```

Expected output

```
1
2
// route to other page and back
1
2
```

Actual output

```
2
// route to other page and back
2
```

Comment: There's obviously something wrong in this question... code in `.subscribe(...)` should happn in order, so if you get a `2` logged, you have to get that `1` logged as well. Are you sure that `2` you see as output doesn't come from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your code, sorry. I think you can use

Your service

```
observer: Subject<any>=new Subject<any>; //<--we create a Subject
observable: this.observer.asObservable();

setKey(key, item){
    localStorage.setItem(key, item);
    observer.next("change");
    //or observer.next(key);
}
constructor(){
     //nothing, it's not necesary windows.addEventListener
}
```

Your component

```
constructor(private storage:Storage){}
//In ngOnInit
ngOnInit()
{
   //we subscribe to observable
   this.storage.observable.subscribe((data:any)=>
   {
        console.log(data) //output: "change" //or "test"
        console.log("1");
        console.log("2");
   }
   storage.setKey('test', 'test'); //<--call to setKey
}
```